# Drawing a Bitmap to a VideoFrame with OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, webrtc, android-bitmap

I am working on a class that extends Camera2Capturer in order to get the frame from the camera, modify it and then feed it back to the observer callback.
I am able to get the frame, transform it to Bitmap, modify that Bitmap to what I want and then draw it with OpenGL to a new VideoFrame that I return with `capturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);`

The problem is, my newly created videoFrame is stretched. The bitmap is correct when I inspect it, but the video frame drawn is stretch on the side. I tried it on different device with different resolution but the problem is exactly the same everywhere.

Here is the code from my startCapture method:

```
@Override
    public void startCapture(int width, int height, int fps) {
        super.startCapture(width, height, fps);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        captureThread = new Thread(() -> {

            final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(1f, -1f);
            TextureBufferImpl buffer = new TextureBufferImpl(width, height, VideoFrame.TextureBuffer.Type.RGB, textureHandle[0], matrix, surTexture.getHandler(), yuvConverter, null);

            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

            try {
                while (true) {
                    surTexture.getHandler().post(() -> {
                        if (needsToRedrawFrame) {
                            VideoFrame lastFrameReceived = capturerObs.getLastFrameReceived();

                            //This is the bitmap I want to draw on the video frame
                            Bitmap bitmapToDraw = drawingCanvasView.getmBitmap();


                            //At this point, bitmmapToDraw contains the drawing and the frame captured from the camera overlayed
                            //Now we need to convert it to fit into the onFrameCaptured callback (requires a VideoFrame).

                            // Set filtering
                            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

                            // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
                            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmapToDraw, 0);

                            bitmapToDraw.recycle();

                            //The bitmap is drawn on the GPU at this point.

                            //We transfer it to the VideoFrame
                            VideoFrame.I420Buffer i420Buf = yuvConverter.convert(buffer);

                            VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(i420Buf, 0, lastFrameReceived.getTimestampNs());

                            ogCapturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
                            needsToRedrawFrame = false;
                        }
                    });

                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogHelper.logError(CapturerObserverProxy.class, "RMTEST THIS > " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        });
        captureThread.start();
    }
```

Here is how the bitmapToDraw look like:
[image: Bitmap]

And here is how the videoFrame drawn on the SurfaceView look like:
[image: VideoFrame]

What am I missing exactly? I am not familiar with OpenGL at all.

Comment: "//The bitmap is drawn on the GPU at this point." I don't see the code that does that

Comment: That's pretty much my understanding so far. I don't have a clue how OpenGL works and how it draws straight on the GPU. 
All I know is: after those few lines, the buffer contains the drawn image. So I assume it was done.

I am probably wrong on this, it is all assumption at that point.

Comment: I guess the openGL code that draws is somewhere else then

Comment: Please share the code to get "getLastFrameReceived()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the frame was drawn correctly. But the frame had a different resolution than the Surface where it is actually drawn, hence the stretching.
I had to resize (while maintaining the aspect ratio!) the bitmap that I was about to draw. If the bitmap has the same size as the Surface it is rendered on, then it won't be stretched.

Comment: @Anael..Please share getLastFrame explaination